# Foreign key constraint violation when deleting audited Hibernate envers Entity

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, hibernate-envers

I have a situation that looks like the following :

Two entities Employee and EmployeeHty :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Audited
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_hty")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeHty {

    @EmbeddedId
    private HtyCompositePrimaryKey htyCompositePrimaryKey;

    @Column(name = "revision_type")
    private Integer revisionType;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

}

@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class HtyCompositePrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "revision_id")
    private EmployeeAuditRevision auditRevision;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_audit_revision")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RevisionEntity(EmployeeRevisionListener.class)
public class EmployeeAuditRevision {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column
    private Long revisionId;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column
    private Date revisionDate;

    @Column
    private String userUid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

An employee could have himself as boss. So i end up with this values in my database :

employee

| id | name | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 1 |
| 2 | Melanie | null |

employee_hty

| id | revision_id | revision_type | name | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 102 | 0 | Jack | 1 |
| 2 | 103 | 0 | Melanie | null |

revision types :
0 : created
1: updated
2: deleted

I want to **delete manually** Jack from the employee table and **add a delete revision** using SQL

```
INSERT INTO employee_hty VALUES (1, 104, 2, Jack, 1);

DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = 1;
```

Here is the situation i would like to be in :

employee

| id | name | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Melanie | null |

employee_hty

| id | revision_id | revision_type | name | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 104 | 2 | Jack | 1 |
| 1 | 102 | 0 | Jack | 1 |
| 2 | 103 | 0 | Melanie | null |

But since employee_hty has a foreign key constraint that link the column employee_id(table employee_hty) to the column id(table employee) it is not possible to do this. And i would like to have your thoughts on the matter.

Is deleting the foreign key constraint could be the solution ?

*NB: some details were omitted for the purpose of simplicity. *

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the constraint or don’t populate the column for deletes

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm not sure about the second suggestion though (don't populate the column for deletes) since there is already a line in the employee_hty which has a reference to the id of the employee i want to delete (That line was inserted when the employee is created the first time.) and i want to keep this information in the audit table.